# How can I make this query work only using JPA (or Hibernate) API?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following method somewhere in my code:

```
public boolean isFooHere(final Foo foo) {
    final Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FooBar WHERE foo_id = " + foo.getId());
    final long count = (Long) query.uniqueResult();
    if (count == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

But I think having hardcoded SQL query is not good practice.

How can have the same functionality using only JPA API?

Comment: This is also vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Look into Prepared Statements.

Comment: @aryamccarthy I do not think there is anyway to pass custom string for foo.id..

Comment: You can use criteria query or NamedQuery in JPA. Best practice would be creating a class for just your sql queries and keep them as a static variable. I prefer NamedQuery because queries are in their own entity's classes and more readable than other ways

Comment: Clearly that is trivial with JPQL so no idea why you even contemplate using "Hibernate API" (and losing portability)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this. Use class instead of table name in the query and entity field instead of column

```
Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery(
        "select count(*) from Foo f where f.id=:id");
query.setLong("id", foo.getId());
Long count = (Long)query.uniqueResult();
```

Comment: Return type of count query may be different, so using `java.lang.Number` while casting query result then converting it with its metods like intValue(), longValue()  will be more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Hibernate Criteria Library](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html).

For Instance;

```
public Boolean isFooHere(final Foo foo) {

   Criteria criteria = createCriteria();

   criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("foo.id", foo.getId()));

   if(criteria.uniqueResult() != null)
      return true;

   return false;
}
```

Note that in "foo.id", foo is your db table name.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
public boolean isFooHere(final Foo foo) {
    final Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(FooBar.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("foo", foo));
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
    final Long result = (Long) criteria.uniqueResult();
    return result > 0;
}
```